# What's this manga about a guy in debt who goes to a fantasy world?

Tags: zero-no-shiniki

To my knowledge it only has 1 chapter and I want to know more about it.

The guy is in debt and so he has become a shut in until he falls asleep and goes to a world of fantasy. He meets a girl and they partner up on a mission they completed it but goes on an adventure and the girl ends up dead by some monster. He teleports in time before he is killed and he wakes up. He checks his balance and he made the exact amount from his amount in the game. He then goes to the hospital and finds out that the girl may be dead. Next chapter was suppose to reveal if that part is true.

Can someone help me find this manga?

Comment: Welcome to the Anime/Manga SE. Could you clarify what you meant by "it has only one chapter"? Later you talk about a "next chapter", so I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 6):

The manga is **[Zero no Shiniki](http://myanimelist.net/manga/76191/Zero_no_Shiniki)**, and like you said, there's only one chapter translated so far.

Synopsis from [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=105763):

> [image: Cover]
>
> Kanzaki Rei is an avid gamer, but one day he hit rock-bottom due to his debts. During the night while sleeping, a strange phenomenon happened and sent him inside the game he previously played. A world of life and death awaits.